# I'm trying to install package using 'npm i react-draft-wysiwyg' command but it not working

Tags: reactjs, npm, react-draft-wysiwyg

*While I'm trying to install package using 'npm i react-draft-wysiwyg'  it is giving me following error:*

```
`npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: my-app@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: react@18.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR! react@"^18.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR! peer react@">=0.14.0" from draft-js@0.11.7
npm ERR! node_modules/draft-js
npm ERR! draft-js@"^0.11.7" from the root project
npm ERR! peer draft-js@"^0.10.x || ^0.11.x" from react-draft-wysiwyg@1.14.7
npm ERR! node_modules/react-draft-wysiwyg
npm ERR! react-draft-wysiwyg@"" from the root project
npm ERR! 1 more (react-dom)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"0.13.x || 0.14.x || ^15.0.0-0 || 15.x.x || ^16.0.0-0 || ^16.x.x || ^17.x.x" from react-draft-wysiwyg@1.14.7
npm ERR! node_modules/react-draft-wysiwyg
npm ERR! react-draft-wysiwyg@"" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
```

Comment: react-draft-wysiwyg doesn't support react 18.x.x. version that support react 18.x.x not published. https://github.com/jpuri/react-draft-wysiwyg/pull/1245

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem but at the end I got a solution. 100% solved. Just use this command in your project:

```
npm config set legacy-peer-deps true
```